# How to get EnvDTE.Command from CommandBarButton in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to find all enabled resharper Commands via the menus. I can find all the menu items using the following code.  However I cannot find how to get the actual command from the DTE commands collection.

```
var resharper = ((CommandBars)_dte.Application.CommandBars)["RESHARPER"];
var refactor = (CommandBarPopup)resharper.Controls["&Refactor"].Control;
foreach (var c in refactor.Controls)
{
    var cbb = c as CommandBarButtonClass;
    if (cbb != null)
    {
        yield return new VoiceCommand
        {
            Command = _dte.Commands.Item(???),
            Key = cbb.accName,
        };  
    }
}
```

What property should I use to look up the command (??? above)?

Thank you,
Erick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [CommandInfo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.commands.commandinfo.aspx), like this:

```
Guid guid;
int id;
_dte.Commands.CommandInfo(cbb, out guid, out id);
yield return new VoiceCommand
{
    Command = _dte.Commands.Item(guid, id),
    Key = cbb.accName,
};
```